# Menu dose not show on Action bar android

Tags: android-actionbar

I am using Holo.theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

My menu file is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="200" app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_compose" android:title="@string/action_settings1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always" />
```

My main_activity_java file is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    //return true;
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Menu is showing on clicking hardware button of phone instead of on Action Bar. Please help me. I want to show these on action bar

Comment: Change MainActivity to `extends ActionBarActivity` @Onkar

Comment: Thanx, But If I change MainActivity to extends ActionBarActivity then I also have to change the theme of an app and I don't want that. Here I'm used Theme.Holo

Comment: Have you tried `android:showAsAction="always"`? As your current menu file shows error at my end. @Onkar

Comment: Yes, I tried all combinations but it dose not gives results. @Pooja

Comment: Above menu file is small part of original Menu file @Pooja

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep Holo theme then use following answer.

First of all remove Appcompat lib (If it exists) from your project depending on the IDE you are using.

Change TargetSDK and compile SDK to 20.

In your menu.xml do following changes.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"                   
           android:title="@string/action_settings"
           android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
           android:orderInCategory="200"
           android:showAsAction="always" />

     <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"  
           android:title="@string/action_settings1"
           android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
           android:orderInCategory="100" 
           android:showAsAction="always" />
```

I hope this can help.